# How to change value of existing variables in Cruise control config file

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

I have created a variable in cruise control configuration file

I want to change the value of this variable in cruise control later during execution. Basically what I want is while executing task1, value of 'MyVariable' should be say 'val1' and while executing task2, value should be say 'val2'.

One more thing that I want is, there should be no manual interaction or manual assignment from ui, the value should be changed automatically.

Can anybody please help me in achieving this? Any suggestion/ inputs would be great help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm using the following approach to compile one MSBuild with different parameters (ccnet 1.8):

```
<cb:define name="Build">
  <msbuild>
     <some_parameter>$(MyVariable)</some_parameter>
     <other_parameter>parameter_value</other_parameter>
  </msbuild>
</cb:define>
```

and then in tasks section:

```
<cb:Build MyVariable="val1" />
<cb:Build MyVariable="val2" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If those values of MyVariable are constant (I mean always the same for given task) then I'd use [preprocessor](http://cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Configuration_Preprocessor). Then you can override the value with cb:scope.

For example, here's what I do with projects configuration:

```
<cb:scope 
    Project.Name = "ProjectName - Feedback - Integration tests"
    Project.ShortName = "project-name-feedback-quick"
    Project.Category = "Project Name - Feedback"
    Project.Description =  "Run integration tests"
>

    <project name="$(Project.Name)" description="$(Project.Description)">               
        <artifactDirectory>$(CIRootFolderPath)\$(Project.ShortName)\Artifacts</artifactDirectory>
        <workingDirectory>$(CIRootFolderPath)\$(Project.ShortName)\WorkingDir</workingDirectory>
        <state type="state" directory="$(CIRootFolderPath)\$(Project.ShortName)" />
```

So you would surround each `<task>` with `<cb:scope>` block and redefine value of MyVariable in there.

Comment: My variable is not constant. I.e. I want its values to be changed at runtime. My Problem is that I have several projects which needs these variables and I cant bring all projects under one scope. And creating scope makes variable unaccessible to projects outside the scope. It would be great if I can define a global variable and later change its value as per requirement. Basically my requirement is to compile one MSbuild two times with two different parameters. Any idea, how to achieve this?

Comment: So I understand these 2 different parameters are not the same, but depend somehow on what happens during the build? I don't really have an idea at the moment how to solve it best, especially through CCNet. 
Maybe you can "wrap it up" in another msbuild task, that would take care of it, and ccnet would just execute that wrapper task...